# How to preserve rx Scheduler without getting it as a method parameter?

Tags: rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

If I do something like this:

```
Observable.just(1)
.flatMap(
    //inner chain
    Observable.just(2)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
)
.map(// we are in the inner chain thread! //)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
.subscribe()
```

then inner thread will "leak" to the main observable chain.
How to preserve original thread?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean "leak"? Do you mean a memory leak? Other resource leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the same scheduler before and after the `flatMap`

```
Scheduler scheduler = ...

Observable.just(1)
    .subscribeOn(scheduler)
    .flatMap(v -> Observable.just(2).subscribeOn(newThread()))
    .observeOn(scheduler)
    .subscribe()
```

In case you want to return to the exact same thread, you can either specify a single threaded scheduler:

```
 scheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadedExecutor());
```

use the not really for-public-consumption

```
 scheduler = new SingleScheduler();
```

or take any of the standard schedulers and use the RxJava 2 Extension project's [SharedScheduler](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#sharedscheduler):

```
 scheduler = new SharedScheduler(Schedulers.computation());
```

Comment: Yeah, but problem is main chain's subscribeOn() is invoked somewhere with subscribe() (for example in presenter) and it seams when you want to apply new operators with new scheduler to observable in different module (not a presenter) there is no native way afterwards to preserve scheduler that presenter specifies, except to pass it through args, which is sad.

Comment: Your API has to be redesigned to allow the customization of that scheduler, or just leave it to the consumer to define via subscribeOn.